# Hard decisional problem on bilinear groups

Tags: cryptanalysis

Problem: Given $g, g^a, g^b, g^c \in G$ and an efficient bilinear map $e:G \times G \longrightarrow G_T$, distinguish $g^{abc}$ from a random element of $G$.

Is it a hard problem?

Comment: Have you any ideas or directions on how to go about this? It seems like this is a task that is asked of you and we do require indications of effort for that on this site, so we can give hints in the comments.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes problem is not clear. What is the usage of the bilinear map here? All, the elements are from $G$ not $G_T$

Comment: @kelalaka It seems like a natural follow-on question of the fact that decisional Diffie-Helman($g$, $g^a$, $g^b$, $g^{ab}$) is easily solvable in $G$ because we can check whether $e(g,g^{ab})=e(g^a,g^b)$ in $G_T$.

Comment: @Anna If you can allay Maarten's concerns about how the question arises, I can make some remarks.

Comment: Most of the hard decisional problems on pairing that I know are to distinguish a random element of $G_T$ from a power of $e(g,g)$,  e.g. given $g, g^a, g^b, g^c$, it is hard to distinguish $e(g,g)^{abc}$ from random element in $G_T$, except the Decisional Linear problem (DLP). So I tried to read the proof of hardness of DLP to find an idea for my question but I didn't understand. I have self-studied crypto hence there are many gaps in my knowledge. If you mind giving an answer, please advise me good references for proving hardness of problems in crypto. I have good background in maths.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing the decisional bilinear Diffie-Hellman problem (DBDH) (see for example [section 4.2 of this survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02826.pdf)). This is not not known to be easy for an arbitrary bilinear pairing. It is often taken as a hardness assumption in pairing-based cryptography, but as ever, this is an assumption. Practically speaking, there have been no better proposals for solving DBDH other than solving the discrete logarithm problem in either $G$ or $G_T$. If one could solve computational Diffie-Hellman (CDH) in $G$ or $G_T$, then DBDH would also be solvable, but it is not clear how DBDH would help to solve CDH or any other standard hardness assumption let alone the discrete logarithm. As such DBDH is taken to be a stronger assumption than CDH and discrete logarithm in the groups $G$ and $G_T$, but a weaker assumption than decisional Diffie-Hellman (DDH) in $G$. Given the inability to show equivalence between these assumptions, it merits its own place in the hardness assumption hierarchy for now.

Comment: I thought this too at first. But OP is asking about distinguishing $g^{ABC} $ from random in the source group $G$, whereas DBDH is to distinguish $e(g, g) ^{ABC} $ from random in the target group $G_T$.

Comment: @Mikero Good point. The problem is no harder than DBDH since we can construct $e(g,g)^{ABC}=e(g,g^{ABC})$ and then use our DBDH solver, but I cannot see a reverse construction.

Comment: @DanielS Thank you for your remarks. I couldn't see a reverse construction either so I wondered if the problem is hard.